# Is it possible to call an inner div within an outer div on a stylesheet in one line?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i'm using wordpress and i have an element i want to style... it's called...

```
<h2 class="widgettitle">
```

now, i know i can do,

```
h2.wigettitle {
whatever:css;
}
```

however, the problem i have is that i have multiple widgets with the same title and it effects all of them.

but, this h2.widget title is within another div called "headerarea".

so, in my file it's like...

```
<div id=headerarea">
    <h2 class="widgettitle">
               whatever title
    </h2>
</div>
```

so is it possible to make this specific element do something like, #headerarea.h2.widgettitle or something in my element?

i tried styling the outer div independently, but the inner div is still grabbing styling from somewhere else, so i need to override all of them.

hope this makes sense... thanks for any help guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `#headerarea h2.widgettitle`.  Including a space means to look in the children.  If you include a `>` this means only look in direct children.  Note that if your overrides do not work, add `!important` at the end to ensure they will override any other styles applied.

Comment: yessssss... now it works the way i'd like... thanks so much mash!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the child or descendant selectors to accomplish this. Child selector `>` `#headerarea > h2.widgettitle` select h2 elements with class widgettitle that is a child of element with id headerarea. Descendant selector a space `#headerarea h2.widgettitle` select h2 elements with class widgettitle that is a descendant of element with id headerarea.

Also see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 1):

```
#headerarea .widgettitle {
    /* Put your styles here */
}
```